# Abstract Error when destroying Frames

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, fastmm

After discovering that we had some basic memory leaks I've been giving some of our applications a spring clean.  After plugging FastMM4 into one of our applications I'm getting an abstract error that appears to be when I clear a list of frames

I have a Form with a scroll box on it.  The scrollbox has either a list of results or details.  The results and details are both designed in frames.

First I get a batch of results (upto 25 records) and create the appropriate # of frames

```
var
  Framelist: TList;
  NewSF: TSF;
begin
  Framelist := TList.Create;
  for i := 0 to Batch.Count - 1 do
  begin
    NewSF := TSF.Create(nil);
    NewSF.Name := 'SF' + IntToStr(i);
    NewSF.Parent := ScrollBox1;
    FrameList.Add(NewSF);
  end;
end;
```

When a frame is clicked on the result frames are clear and a detail frame created on the scrollbox in their place.  I have currently deactivated the creation of the detail frame and am concentrating on clearing the frames.

The frames were initially being cleared like this:

```
while FrameList.Count > 0 do
begin
  TSF(FrameList[0]).free;
  FrameList.delete(0);
end;
```

I have also tried like this:

```
for i := 0 to FrameList.Count - 1 do
begin
  SF := FrameList[i];
  SF.Free;
  SF := nil;
end;
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong - either on creation or destruction?

Comment: If that scroll box is destroyed before you call your code, it is that scroll box who destroys those frames since it is their `Parent`. In such case you were operating on dangling pointers.

Comment: @TLama Scrollbox is not destroyed until the application is closed down.

Comment: @J... I've updated to use Generics and the error still persists.  Remember without FastMM hooked in the app works...

Comment: What method is about to be called when you get the error? You can use the debugger to discover that.

Comment: Can't reproduce this, either with `TList` or `TList<TSF>` - using FastMM4.

Comment: A TComponentList can be used to alleviate the problem @Tlama describes, if your investigation reveals that that's the problem. When one of the items in the list gets destroyed, the list gets notified.

Comment: @RobKennedy The last identifiable procedure is Vcl.Controls.Perform. And before that IsCOntrolMouseMsg. None of my methods show in the debugger list in normal run.  Commenting out the ClearFrames method evades the error - but with undesired results

Comment: @RobKennedy TComponentList seems to solve the error.  Can't believe I've not come across that before.

Comment: It solved the problem, but I'm still curious for the source of it... :)

Comment: @TLama I know what you mean...